# How join a list of raw strings?

Tags: python

There is a list

```
list_str = ["first_string", "\nsecond_string"]
join_str = ",".join(list_str)
```

join_str return

"first_string,

second_string"

How can I "first_string,\nsecond_string"

Comment: You have caret return `\n` in one of the strings. You first need to filter it out.

Comment: it should return ```"first_string,\nsecond_string"```

Comment: I don't see any raw strings here.

Comment: join_str contains `"first_string,\nsecond_string"` but if your print it the `\n` will printe as new line so thats why you get it split on two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join command works fine, but when you print the string, it cares about special characters so puts a new line whenever encounter to `\n`.
But you can change the print behavior to escape special characters like this:
Use [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

```
a = "Hello\tWorld\nHello World"
print(repr(a))
# 'Hello\tWorld\nHello World'
```

In your source code it would be like:

```
list_str = ["first_string", "\nsecond_string"]
join_str = ",".join(list_str)
print(repr(join_str))
```

Output:

> first_string,\nsecond_string

Answer (score 2):

Use the \ escape character.

```
list_str = ["first_string", "\\nsecond_string"]
join_str = ",".join(list_str)
print(join_str)

Output: first_string,\nsecond_string
```

Comment: instead of adding double `/` in every special characters, you can simply add `r"hello\tworld\n"` like this to skip them and it translates to `repr("str")`